How to Calculate YUV-PNSR
I am using tools like VVenc and UVG266 and doing some test to encode some different yuv files.
VCCenc gives me results for (Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR),
but UVG266 gives me only (Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR)
How can I calculate the YUV-PSNR using the values provided in the result of the encoding done by UVG266?
